Are there any studies of eigenvalue problems expressed as sums with some vector elements equal to zero?
With a common (generalized) eigenvalue problem
$ A x = \lambda x $
where $x_i \ne 0 $, split x into a sum x = y + z so that y or z has some elements equal to zero. (Alternatively the criteria $x_i \ne 0$ can be avoided if $y_i$ and $z_i$ not both are zero.) The problem now becomes
$ A x = A y + A z = \lambda (y + z) $
If it is so that
$ A y = \lambda_y y $
and
$ A z = \lambda_z z $
Can anything be determined about the relation between y and z and $ \lambda_y $ and $ \lambda_z $?

You should look into invariant subspaces.
